# Optimal Way to Browse Gem Source Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide

I find that browsing source code of open source libraries being used in projects is invaluable. Unfortunately, I find this difficult when developing with ruby on rails. I am accustomed to working inside IDE's that allow me to jump to the definitions of symbols, regardless of whether they are part of an external library.

I use Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OS X to develop, but would be willing to change IDEs for this feature.

I have explored https://github.com/fnando/gem-open as an option, but have yet to find a good editor to integrate this with. Can anyone recommend one? Anyone else have a good method for browsing the sources of gems?

Comment: BTW, gem-open was new to me - I think I'm going to use this frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 has a command line launcher: studio3.

Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Aptana Studio 3:$PATH"
export GEM_EDITOR="studio3"
```

Reload your existing shell environment: `. ~/.bash_profile` and then you can use gem-open with your preferred editor: `gem open rails`

Comment: Cool this looks promising, I hope aptana plays nicely with the directory argument that is passed in by gem open

Comment: Just got around to testing this and it works great. I use fish instead of bash, but just as a note, the spaces in the path might need to be escaped and it should be GEM_OPEN_EDITOR instead of GEM_EDITOR